# Excel display the number of days between 2 dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Microsoft Excel 2016. Cell `B2` contains the date `21-08-16`.

I am using `=DAYS(TODAY(),B2)` and I am getting the result `09-01-00` instead of the integer value `9`. I also tried `=DATEDIF(B2, TODAY(), "d")` with combinations of `INT()` function and I get the same result. How to do this properly ?

Comment: The result is correct, just not in the format as you need. Change the number format to general.

Comment: @MátéJuhász That fixed my problem

Comment: @dimitris93, consider posting an answer to help the next person with the same problem.